# how to copy a string from one tape to another (two tape Turing machine)?

Tags: turing-machines

i have to decide w#w using a two tape Turing machine. I know that u need to copy the last part , that is the part after the # onto the second tape and then compare character by character to see whether those two parts are the same.

My problem is how do i copy that part after the # onto the second tape ?

Any ideas ?

w = (a|b)^*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, this seems very trivial.

You start off on the first tape with a rule that changes state when the `#` is encountered. When `#` is encountered, you move the head to the right, change the state to one that changes when you reach the end of the tape, and begin writing on the second tape whatever is written on the first one.

Comment: yeah, my real problem is the writing of the transition function.

Comment: @user602774 show us what you have so far. And if this is homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: ok this is my problem, when you are moving the head on the first tape to the position after the #, can i keep the head on the second tape stationary ?

Comment: @user602774 does it say in the assignment whether the head is common for all tapes? AFAIK, the tapes are independent and each has its own head.

Comment: yup the tapes are independent but the question doesn't mention about the stay option, maybe i may have to assume it

Comment: @user602774 oh I see what you mean. There are variations which allow a no-op move, but I guess you don't use that. I'd make the second head just go back to the start of the tape.

Comment: when ever i write a transition function, it should be written for both tapes right ? for example T1: a -> a,R : T2 _ -> _,S